# .loc[ ] and pd.Series.nunique function

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

```
df_all = pd.DataFrame.from_records(features_all)
df_all = df_all.loc[:,df_all.apply(pd.Series.nunique) != 1]

df_benign = df_all.loc[df_all['Y'] == 1]
df_Malw = df_all.loc[df_all['Y'] == 0]
```

I was going through a code and came across these statements.
I am not able to understand what .loc and pd.Series.nunique do ?
Executing these statements gives error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`.loc` is an indexing function. You use it to access rows of your data by the index label. For example, if you create a data frame with index of ['a', 'b', 'c'] and you want to access the row with label 'a', you can use .loc:

```
> import pandas as pd
> import numpy as np
> df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.random((3,4)), columns=list('1234'), 
index=list('abc'))
> df
          1         2         3         4
a  0.197580  0.992679  0.258636  0.750934
b  0.668819  0.452229  0.498106  0.424484
c  0.534395  0.951544  0.222347  0.807361
> df.loc['a']
1    0.197580
2    0.992679
3    0.258636
4    0.750934
```

You can also use `.loc` to index a range of items like `df.loc['a':'c']`, but in your code it seems you are both trying to index the row and column in this line:

```
df_all = df_all.loc[:,df_all.apply(pd.Series.nunique) != 1]
```

In that line you can try using `.ix` instead. For the other two lines:

```
df_benign = df_all.loc[df_all['Y'] == 1]
df_Malw = df_all.loc[df_all['Y'] == 0]
```

You are finding all the rows where `df_all['Y'] == 1` and select them with `df_all.loc[ ]`.

Comment: putting .ix instead of .loc helped.

Answer (score 0):

pd.Series.nunique will return unique values within the series. 
.loc can be used to slice the dataframe on the basis of index in the dataframe.